# problems after creating jar file

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I created a GUI in the NetBeans and Then a jar file is generated. Now, when I click on a button to run the program with the jar file, there is no operation after clicking and the results that are tables and graphing data types did not show. How I can fix this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to tell us what your code is supposed to do, and how you exported the code.

Comment: I am using NetBeans IDE 7.4 platform and its clean and build project item to create jar file

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to export a program. You can use it as a java application or an appelet. You probably made it into an appelet when you really want a separate application.

But without you telling us how you made the jar file or what the program is, my guess is as good as anyones.

Comment: I am using NetBeans IDE 7.4 platform and its clean and build project item to create jar file.

Answer (score 0):

After you compile the program successfully, you can run it. Assuming that your program uses a standard look and feel — such as the Java, Windows, or GTK+ look and feel — you can use the **interpreter** to run the program without adding anything to your class path. For example:

```
java HelloWorldSwing
```

For programs that use a nonstandard look and feel or any other nonstandard code package, you must make sure that the necessary classes are in the class path. For example:

**Solaris/Linux**

> java -classpath.:/home/me/lnfdir/newlnf.jar HelloWorldSwing

**Microsoft Windows**

> java -classpath .;C:\java\lnfdir\newlnf.jar HelloWorldSwing